# Enable security on kibana after installation with Helm

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-helm, efk

I installed EFK stack using Helm charts which is working very fine but with zero security.

I checked the minimal security for elasticsearch:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/security-minimal-setup.html

which shows that I have to add xpack variables in elasticsearch.yml files on all nodes but with installation with helm, there are no yml files generated.

Can anyone help how to enable security on kibana.

Comment: Which helm chart? Have you checked the docs for the chart to see which helm values are accepted and if any of them fit your needs? https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/main/kibana#how-to-use-kibana-with-security-authentication-and-tls-enabled